# Query model for all possible values of a column - Ruby Rails

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I'm learning programming in general, and Ruby specifically; in the course we are developing an app like rottentomatoes.

I need to query the model from the controller, to render in the view the distinct values in that specific column.

I have this piece of haml to embed the result on the template:

```
  = form_tag movies_path, :method => :get do
    Include:
    - @all_ratings.each do |rating|
      = rating
      = check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]"
    = submit_tag 'Refresh'
```

I have `@all_ratings` in the controller, I have tried `movie[attr_rating]` , `Movie(:rating)`... And I don't know what else to throw to it.

I do not want to hardcode the values (`['G','PG','PG-13','R']`) in the controller, but learn how to query the model.

Comment: You cannot query a column for all its "possible" values, that makes no sense. Are you trying to query a *validation* for the values it will allow? Or are you using an [enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) to get the possible values for that? Or do you just want to get the distinct values for a column? You need to include some code to show us what it is you're trying to do. We can't help you without at least *some* information about the column and model.

Comment: Sorry for the poor explanation. I want to get the distinct values for a column.

Comment: Then your question has been well answered in the linked duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still earningl to search for answers